# Export grid of images from Inkscape to individual PNG files

Tags: inkscape, export, png, grids

How can I export a grid of icons from Inkscape to a series of PNG files?

The icons are aligned correctly in a grid that define their final shape. Here is a sample of the bottom right corner:

[image]

I want the resulting PNG to be the size of each of those grid areas, with the actual icon correctly positioned within (the position as shown here).

I don't care so much about the name of the bits, I can rename them later. Though if there is a way to assign each a file name prior to export that'd also be great (so I can redo it later without a problem).

Answer (score 3):

For reference, this is how I do it now using ImageMagick.

1. Export to a PNG of the right size for the desired icon size (for example, a 960x512 image for a grid of 15,8 icons of 64x64 size). This includes all icons in one image.
2. Split them up using this command: `convert ../icons.png -crop 64x64 +repage +adjoin icon-%d.png`
3. Link individual files `ln -s icon-111.png cancel.png` (this lets me re-export later and not lose the desired filenames)

Comment: Note that recent versions of ImageMagick are using command `magick` instead of `convert`: https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

Answer (score 1):

If you plan early enough, you can put your images on individual backgrounds of the right size, and then group every icon.

Then you can select the whole area, choose **Export**, there **Selection**, and mark the option box **batch export**.

From the look, your current image would produce Icons of different size, since each group is as big as the minimum enclosing rectangle.